# order statistics

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1,..., X_n$ are i.i.d. continuous r.v. with distribution function $F(x)$, and density function $f(x)$.

$X_{(1)}<\cdots<X_{(n)}$ are the order statistics.

I've already showed that the distribution function of $X_{(k)}$ is

$G_k(x)=\sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j}F(x)^j(1-F(x))^{n-j}$.

Now I'm asked to prove that the density function of $X_{(k)}$ is

$g_k(x)= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k}f(x)$.

I'm supposed to do the derivative of $G_k$ w.r.t $x$ and obtain the density above.

However, I get to $g_k(x)=\sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j}\cdot \left(jF(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{n-j}f(x)-F(x)^{j}(n-j)(1-F(x))^{n-j-1}f(x) \right)=\sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{n-j-1}f(x)(j-nF(x))$

where I remain stuck...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you show the steps you have gone through?

Comment: It would be helpful to go through your work to identify where you made mistake

Comment: @SA-255525 I've just edited the question. Thanks for the interest in this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution function is correct:

$$G_k(x)=\sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j}F(x)^j(1-F(x))^{n-j}$$

The correct density function is (no sum)

$$g_k(x)=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k}f(x).$$

Finding the density by directly differentiating the sum is difficult. Alternatively, the distribution function can be shown to have an integral representation in terms of the beta function

$$G_k(x) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}\int_{0}^{F(x)}t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt,$$

and the density function is obtained directly by taking the derivative of the integral using Leibniz's rule.

We can derive the integral representation by induction.

Let

$$H(k,p) = \sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}$$

Then

$$H(0,p) = 1,\\H(1,p) = 1 - (1-p)^n= \frac{n!}{(n-1)!(1-1)!}\int_{0}^{p}t^{1-1}(1-t)^{n-1}\,dt$$

Assume

$$H(k-1,p) = \frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!(k-2)!}\int_{0}^{p}t^{k-2}(1-t)^{n-k+1}\,dt.$$

Integrate by parts to obtain

$$H(k-1,p) = {n \choose k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k+1}+\frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}\int_{0}^{p}t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt.$$

From the definition of $H$ as a sum we have,

$$H(k,p) = H(k-1,p) - {n \choose k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k+1}.$$

Hence,

$$H(k,p) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}\int_{0}^{p}t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt.$$

Now substitute with $p = F(x)$ to obtain

$$G_k(x) =H(k,F(x))= \frac{n!}{(n-k)!(k-1)!}\int_{0}^{F(x)}t^{k-1}(1-t)^{n-k}\,dt.$$

**Direct Derivation:**

To get the density function directly, start with your formula

$$g_k(x)\\=\sum^n_{j=k} {n \choose j}\cdot \left(jF(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{n-j}f(x)-F(x)^{j}(n-j)(1-F(x))^{n-j-1}f(x) \right)\\=f(x)\left[\sum^n_{j=k} j{n \choose j} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{n-j}-\sum^{n-1}_{j=k} (n-j){n \choose j} F(x)^{j}(1-F(x))^{n-j-1}\right].$$

Note that

$$j{n \choose j}=n{n-1 \choose j-1},\\ (n-j){n \choose j}=n{n-1 \choose j}.$$

Then

$$g_k(x)\\=nf(x)\left[\sum^n_{j=k} {n-1 \choose j-1} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-(j-1)}-\sum^{n-1}_{j=k} {n-1 \choose j} F(x)^{j}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-j}\right].$$

The first sum is

$$\sum^n_{j=k} {n-1 \choose j-1} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-(j-1)} \\={n-1 \choose k-1}F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k} + \sum^n_{j=k+1} {n-1 \choose j-1} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-(j-1)}$$

The second sum is

$$\sum^{n-1}_{j=k} {n-1 \choose j} F(x)^{j}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-j)} \\=\sum^n_{j=k+1} {n-1 \choose j-1} F(x)^{j-1}(1-F(x))^{(n-1)-(j-1)}.$$

The remaining sums cancel leaving

$$g_k(x) = n{n-1 \choose k-1}F(x)^{k-1}(1-F(x))^{n-k}f(x)$$

Comment: Many thanks for your interest in this question. Your answer is really useful, even though it's not what I was asked to do... =) I upvoted your answer, but I think I cannot accept it, since I have to reach the density by derivation. I'm sorry. If solving it by derivation takes too much of your time, could you at least give me some hints on how to proceed by derivation? or send me a url?  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome - I found the derivative directly from the sum and added the derivation to the answer.

Comment: @RRL very clear explanation of combinatorics.i was stuck at this point.

Comment: @SA-255525: Thanks.  I knew the integral shortcut, but I decided to grind through the second derivation as requested.