# Order Statistics distribution equations

Tags: statistics

> Distribution of $k$<sup>th</sup> Order Statistic
>
> For i.i.d. Res $X_1,\dots,X_n$, with CDF $F(x)$ and PDF $f(x)$, the distribution of the $k$<sup>th</sup> order statistic $X_{(k)}$ is $$\begin{align}
> F_{(k)}(x)&=\sum_{i=k}^n{n\choose i}[F(x)]^i[1-F(x)]^{n-i}\\
> f_{(k)}(x)&=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}[F(x)]^{k-1}[1-F(x)]^{n-k}f(x)
> \end{align}$$

Here is something we read in a lecture, however I do not understand the theory behind $F_{(k)}(x)$ and how to derive it to get $f_{(k)}(x)$.

The first equation $F_{(k)}(x)$ is the order statistic and is used for certain things like what is the distribution of the 5th part of a 12-part machine failing where all parts have a iid of failure, but how did they use this info to get that equation?

Also how do you differentiate to get $f_{(k)}(x)$? I tried but one big problem is the sigma and the other is that I am getting more terms even after simplifying.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/861190/148510 for a derivation of the pdf by differentiation. It takes some effort.

Comment: Thank you so much it really helped, just doesnt show how G(k)(x) is derived as the OP already knew how.

Comment: Thnks a lot everything makes sense now! math is awesome and so are you :) .......